# Connecting an Azure virtual network to an external VPN gateway

Tags: azure, vpn

I have a virtual network on Azure and would like to establish a VPN connection using the encryption details and shared key that I have received. All the Azure documentation that I've found for point-to-site and site-to-site VPN setups seem to not cover this case, but only cover how an external router can connect to a VPN gateway which has been created on Azure. Is the set up that I want possible with Azure virtual networks or do I need to configure the VPN connection on each VM that I want on the VPN?

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a VNet-to-VNet connection as per this [article](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-load-balance/)

Comment: So the `Set-AzureVNetGatewayKey` at the end of that post is telling Azure what the preshared key of the other network is? Shouldn't there also be a way to tell Azure more details, such as the encryption algorithm etc.?

Comment: Yes, the key is the shared key.The ability to control encryption settings, etc for virtual gateways is relatively new and the documentation may not yet have been updated to reflect it.